# why isn't this window function working? I can't use a group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, window-functions

I am working in `MySQL` and I have this table:

```
url             x   y   count *
abc.com         1   1   2
abc.com         2   1   2
xyz.com         1   56  5
xyz.com         2   71  5
xyz.com         3   59  5
xyz.com         4   67  5
xyz.com         5   59  5
```

and I'm trying to run this code:

```
count(dh.x) over(partition by dh.url)
```

in order to get a `count of 2 for url of abc.com and a count of 5 for url of xyz.com to be the denominator I divide by in my query below...`

that window function is nested in this larger CTE:

```
, stdev_estimates AS (   
    SELECT dh.url
    , CASE SUM(SQUARE(dh.x - xmean)) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE SQRT(SUM(SQUARE(dh.x - xmean)) / (count(dh.x) over(partition by dh.url)) - 1) END AS xstdev
    , SQRT(SUM(SQUARE(dh.y - ymean)) / (count(dh.x) over(partition by dh.url)) - 1) AS ystdev
    , count(dh.x) over(partition by dh.url) 'denom'
    FROM date_hits dh
    INNER JOIN mean_estimates m ON m.url = dh.url
    GROUP BY dh.url, m.xmean, m.ymean, dh.x, dh.y
)
select *
from stdev_estimates
```

but when I try to run the inner subselect, I keep getting this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 49
>   Column 'date_hits.x' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

But it doesn't make sense because I thought this was a workaround needing a group by for the `dh.x`? I thought you don't need group by's if you're using an aggregating function.

Bottom line is I need to not group by `dh.x` because it breaks out my table into 7 rows when I'm aggregating everything down to:

```
url            xstdev    ystdev
abc.com       .12345    .5679
xyz.com       .23455    .79023
```

Comment: I cannot spot `date_hits.x` anywhere in your code...

Comment: @stickybit: that's the alias for `date_hits`

Answer (score 1):

What's *within* the window function must be an expression that complies with the outer `group by`.

If you remove `dh.x` from the `group by` clause, you cannot use it alone, you need an aggregate function on it.

Presumably, you want to replace this:

```
count(dh.x) over(partition by dh.url)
```

With:

```
sum(count(dh.x)) over(partition by dh.url)
```

Comment: but if i sum(count()) then it's summing the counts so I'm getting 4 for abc.com and 25 for xyz.com instead of 2 and 5..I thought count was an aggregate function

Comment: found a fix by just doing this calculation in the CTE before it